# Remove multiple div's in reactjs via Remove button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to remove the multiple `div`'s that have been generated via the add button. 
I'm having trouble in understanding how can I send the parent div's id into delete method passed from the child div. Also, if I can store the div's id into a state to perform the deletion process. My code is as follows. I appreciate your inputs and suggestions.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      names: [],
      inputValue: '',
      id: [],
      count: 1,
      hostname: '',
      devname: '',
      sID: '',
    }
    this.addRow = this.addRow.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    this.deleteRow = this.deleteRow.bind(this)
  }

addRow() {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })
    console.log(`Increase count: ${this.state.count}`)
  };

  renderDivs() {
    let count = this.state.count, uiItems = [];
    var { names } = this.state;
    let options2 = names.map(name2 => {
      return { value: name2.name, label: name2.name };
    })
    while (count--)
      uiItems.push(
        <div className="newHost" id="dynamic">
          <div className="hostInput">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name"
              onChange={this.handleChangeHN.bind(this)}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="hostInput">
            <Select
              placeholder="Pick Dev Name..."
              styles={colourStyles}
              options={options2}
              onChange={this.handleChangeDN}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="hostInput">
            <button className="btn btn-danger" type="button" onClick={this.deleteRow}>Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    return uiItems;
  }

  deleteRow(currentID) {
    // const changedID = this.state.id.filter(i => i.id !== currentID)
    // this.setState({changedID});
    // console.log(`Clicked: ${currentID}`);
    // this.setState({ count: this.state.count - 1 })
    console.log("delete");
  };

render() {
    let options = sData.map(name => {
      return { value: name.name, label: name.name };
    })

    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="form-wrapper">
          <Toolbar />
          <form className="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label className="label1">Select SaleID</label> <hr />
            <div>
              <Select
                value={this.state.inputValue}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                options={options}
              />
              <div style={{ color: 'red', marginTop: '5px' }}>
                {this.state.validationError}
              </div>
              <br />
            </div>
            <label className="label1">Create New Sale</label>
            <hr />
            <div className="addButton">
              <button type="button" onClick={this.addRow}>Add</button>
              {this.renderDivs()}
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div className="submitButton">
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: your `deleteRow` function should be `deleteRow(event)` and inside this function you can access the id of the parent:
`event.target.parentNode.id`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by removing multiple divs. But in the following [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dynamic-list-example-functional-components-3k309) I've created an example of a dynamic list. Store the dynamic array in state & update the state with add/remove. It's important to get the data structure right then it's easier to handle updates.

Comment: Where are you defining `sData`?

Comment: @MattCroak - the sData have nothing to do with delete button, but still to explain, it is being used to pull data from cache file and display in a drop down.

Comment: @alan_jouhar: I am not sure what do you mean by parentNode.id.
Here I want to pass the parent div id ("dynamic) in deleteRow() method, then to fetch that id passed a parameter and than update the state accordingly. But I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: @ShivaniBali I was trying to run your code in a codepen to debug but sData was undefined and I am unable to render your code as is. Can you provide an example of what it would look like?

Comment: @ShivaniBali you want to remove this div: `<div className="newHost" id="dynamic">` wright? if yes, then `event.target.parentNode.id` is this div.

Comment: @MattCroak: Sure, please see something like below:
[
    {
        "status": "In service",
        "comments": "Test",
        "lastModifiedBy": "shivB",
        "country": "CANADA",
        "floor": "GROUND",
        "name": "Sell123",
        "city": "MISSISSAUGA",
        "room": "ABC1",
        "postalCode2": "L4Z",
        "versionNumber": 1,
    },

Comment: @alan_jouhar: Yes correct.
Please tell me if I am correct here : so I create a state variable named ID and then update the state from deleteRow(event) method like following:
```
const changedID = this.state.id.filter(i => i.id !== event.target.parentNode.id)
 this.setState({changedID});

```

Answer (score 0):

When programming in react you should first forget about html ids. When you add or delete a row you are dealing with data and not html elements. Your example seems not to contain all of the components code and is missing the functions `handleChangeHN` and `handleChangeHN` so I will only make an example of the relevant parts of the code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rows: [],
    }
    //...
}

addRow() {
    const newRow = {
        name: '',
        devName: '',
    };
    this.setState({ rows: [...this.state.rows, newRow] })
};

deleteRow(position) {
    this.setState({ rows: this.state.rows.filter((_, i) => i !== position) })
}

renderDivs() {
    const { rows } = this.state;
    const options2 = rows.map(name2 => {
      return { value: name2.name, label: name2.name };
    });
    return rows.map( (row, i) => (
        <div className="newHost" key="_{i}">
          <div className="hostInput">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name"
              value={row.name}
              onChange={this.handleChangeHN.bind(this)}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="hostInput">
            <Select
              placeholder="Pick Dev Name..."
              styles={colourStyles}
              options={options2}
              value={row.devName}
              onChange={this.handleChangeDN}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="hostInput">
            <button className="btn btn-danger" type="button" onClick={() => this.deleteRow(i)}>Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    ));
}
```

PS: it is not a good practice to use the iterator as the key `key="_{i}"` but since you only have user input fields they can not be used as an identifier. The other option would be to use a random id generator or just store the click count in the state and use it as the id when adding new rows.

PPS: as a side note, you should **not** bind your components handle functions while rendering like you do `onChange={this.handleChangeHN.bind(this)}`. This will create a new function each time your component is rerendered so it is a slow memory leak. Bind the functions like you did in the constructor or just use the ecmascript 6 syntax `handleChangeHN = () => {...`.

Comment: thank you for the thorough input.
Here instead of rows, I need to use (names) because in it I'm adding the data pulled form backend and need to show that in one of the drop down under the main div.
The above solution doesn't apply completely as I need to delete the parent div but the looping is not done right. I really would need to discuss it more, please let me know if you need the entire source file?